# How to know what suggestion item is selected in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I complete a vscode extension by `vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(selector, new FuncCompletionProvider(),'.')`

I want to listen which suggestion is selected. In the image below，when I click the current item I want to get the `CompletionItem` Info.
[image]

I tried to use the `resolveCompletionItem` function, but before the suggestion is selected `resolveCompletionItem` was triggered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried to use the resolveCompletionItem function, but before the suggestion is selected resolveCompletionItem was triggered.

It appears this is intentional. Per their docs:

> Note that this function is called when completion items are already showing in the UI or when an item has been selected for insertion

'selected' meaning selected in the list, not committed

---

The recommended way to gain insight on when a `CompletionItem` is inserted is using the [`CompletionProvider#command`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem) property:

> An optional command that is executed after inserting this completion. Note that additional modifications to the current document should be described with the additionalTextEdits-property.

**Example usage**:

```js
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('html', new MyCompletionProvider),

    vscode.commands.registerCommand("doTheThing", () => {
      console.log('did the thing!!');
    });
  );
}

class MyCompletionProvider implements vscode.CompletionItemProvider {
    provideCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken, context: vscode.CompletionContext): vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.CompletionItem[] | vscode.CompletionList> {

        const myHTMLCompletionItem: vscode.CompletionItem = new vscode.CompletionItem("myHTML");
        myHTMLCompletionItem.command = {
            title: '',
            command: 'doTheThing'
        };

        return new vscode.CompletionList([myHTMLCompletionItem]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the answer is very useful to me